# enable lables for each cell in bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to set each bar chart cell with lables of A, B and C for all my data to be shown on chart. I tried with data.addColumn('string', 'Alphabets'); but it is not working out.
It shall be easy but i am missing something.

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
 google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

 // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

 // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
 // draws it.
 function drawChart() {

// Create the data table.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var raw_data = [
    ['A', 40],
    ['B', 17],
    ['C', 7]
];
data.addColumn('string', 'Columns');
for (var i = 0; i < raw_data.length; ++i) {
    data.addColumn('number', raw_data[i][0]);
}
data.addRows(1);
data.setValue(0, 0, 'row');
for (var i = 0; i < raw_data.length; ++i) {
    data.setValue(0, i + 1, raw_data[i][1]);
}

 // Set chart options
 var options = {'title':'Megafon 27/10 2011',
             'width':1300,
             'height':600,
     'colors' : ['red', 'blue', 'green']
    };

 // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
 }
```

Comment: You cannot show tooltips without mouseover within the Google Visualization API. You would need to write a custom javascript to write your own tooltips, or otherwise find a way to have the google `svg` to display the tooltips without a mouseover. Either way it's a headache.

Comment: I was asking about having individual labels along x axis or horizontal axis, with the above approach i am unable to show the column names on horizontal axis.

Comment: Could you explain a bit better what you mean? What is it displaying, and what do you want it to display?

Comment: It is displaying the data given in row_data as bars but it is not displaying the column names like A,B and C on the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not formatting your data correctly.

Series names are in separate columns (each column will add a new color to the chart, and a new item to the legend).

Value labels (the names of the X-axis categories) are in the first column of each row. You are doing them backwards, therefore there are no axis labels.

For instance, this code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Data'],
    ['A', 10],
    ['B', 20],
    ['C', 40],
    ['D', 80]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data,{});
}
```

Creates this graph:

[image: Sample Graph]

However, you want to have a different color for each series (which is bad visualization practice). To do that you need to have 4 different columns to get 4 different colors.

To do this you need to reformat your data as follows:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Color 1', 'Color 2', 'Color 3', 'Color 4'],
    ['A', 10, null, null, null],
    ['B', null, 20, null, null],
    ['C', null, null, 40, null],
    ['D', null, null, null, 80]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data,{series: [{color: 'red'},{color: 'orange'},{color: 'yellow'},{color: 'green'}]});
}
```

This comes out like this:

[image: Sample Graph 2]

The issue then is that you have 4 different series in the legend, although they only represent one type of data (and this is why it is bad visualization practice!).

You also get a bit of an ugly looking graph, but that can be fixed with setting the options to `isStacked: true`.

At any rate, I'd just keep the data as it is in your array, and not fiddle with color. But your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks Jmac, awesome you solved my problem with nice examples !